# Suppress Chrome 'Failed to load resource' messages in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a script that uses an XMLHttpRequest to search for a file defined by a relative path, by attempting to resolve that relative path against other same domain absolute paths that the script is aware of, then attempting to load the file from that resolved url. If I encounter a 404, I just try to resolve the files relative path against another absolute path, and try again. For this particular script, its perfectly fine to encounter a 404- however, my console is littered with 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) messages, and I want to suppress them.

There is no error to catch as far as I can see- error cases are handled by the xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange handler, and there is no window.onerror.

Is there any way to suppress these messages?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can from JavaScript. Yet there might be a (hidden) config in the developer tools

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13828211/1048572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13044254/1048572) for the same in Firebug.

Answer (score 52):

This feature was introduced [last year](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124534). You can enable it here: `DevTools`->`Settings`->`General`->`Console`->`Hide network messages`.

[image: Hiding network messages in Chrome DevTools]

See also [Filtering the Console output](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#filtering_the_console_output) and [Additional settings](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#additional_settings) in the devtools documentation.

Comment: Anybody know if there's a way to do this from your JavaScript code? This won't be the default on downstream machines, asking me why there are "errors" and will I be able to "resolve this problem".

Comment: @Appurist-PaulW there is a way, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75848002/343721)

Comment: @JanTuroň Thanks for that clever solution. That's some great workaround code there. However, I don't really want to add something so complex to my client's production server just to hide a red message in the browser console. It seems a bit extreme, but I did ask for a way to do it in code so thank you for that, at least there is a solution if the problem turns out to be a support/QA issue. Of course I'd rather see the default behavior changed in Chrome to not be so in-your-face about a common case of working code. But I'll keep this solution in my back pocket in case. Very clever!

Comment: @Appurist-PaulW it would be indeed an overkill to introduce a ServiceWorker for such a minor issue. On the other hand, SW is a well-supported multipurpose tool that can alleviate the load and simplify the main thread: if the client already has a SW, the tweak from fetch to fetch2 is quite simple and easy to replace if needed. Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 11):

Use `console.clear()` in the `catch` block or error handler function. 
It will clear those request error on the console immediately after it is logged.

**PLEASE NOTE**

From MDN

> Note that in Google Chrome, console.clear() has no effect if the user has selected "Preserve log upon navigation" in the settings.

[Read more about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear)

```js
try {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', 'https://invalidurl', false);
  req.send();
} catch(e) {
  console.clear();
}
```

Should log this

> GET https://invalidurl/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

but it will be cleared.

Comment: But this would clear everything from the console, not just the 404 error

Comment: @schoinh seems like we can... intercept all console messages... clear the console... and make reality, whatever we want it to be

Answer (score 10):

Alas, the browsers print network error in the console if the status code is 4XX or 5XX no matter what. It is possible to filter the errors as Konrad's answer suggests, but those errors are still there (i.e. **they are not suppressed, just filtered**) and they reappear if you uncheck the checkbox again.

To avoid those errors, the simplest solution is not to return 4XX responses from the server, but this is kind of lying and breaking the protocol like politicians do.

The clean solution on the client side can be achieved with these steps:

### 1. Register a service worker to intercept background requests

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("noerr.js").then(_=> navigator.serviceWorker.controller
    ? window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("swready")) // normal reload
    : navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(_=> location.reload()) // first load or Ctrl+F5
);
```

Suppressing works since the custom `swready` event.

### 2. Replace the 4XX and 5XX responses in the service worker

The noerr.js service worker could be written like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    self.skipWaiting(); // update even if other tabs are open in the browser
});

const proxyResponse = orig => orig.status<400 ? orig : new Response(null, {
    status: 202,
    statusText: "Accepted",
    headers: new Headers({
        "Status": orig.status,
        "StatusText": orig.statusText
    })
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', e => e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request).then(proxyResponse)
));
```

If the server responds 4XX or 5XX, the SW intercepts the request and returns [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) status code instead in accordance to the standard:

> 202 Accepted response status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not have started yet. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. 202 is non-committal, meaning that there is no way for the HTTP to later send an asynchronous response indicating the outcome of processing the request. It is intended for cases where another process or server handles the request, or for batch processing.

The process mentioned in the quote is our ServiceWorker which returns the original HTTP status code in the `Status` header.

### Example

```
window.addEventListener("swready", _=> {
    // suppressing network errors works since now
    fetch("nonexistent.html").then(r =>
        r.headers.get("Status")==404 && console.log("Server says 404")
        // no error appears in browser console
    )
});
```

Now instead of console.log, the correct approach is to `throw` in case when the response is considered errorneous, and optionally catch it later (uncaught exceptions promote to console error).

### Seamless solution

To achieve this, we can write a `fetch2` function that acts like [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), but doesn't write console errors on 4XX and 5XX:

```
const fetch2 = (req, opt) => fetch(req, opt).then(res =>
    res.status!=202 ? res : new Response(null, {
        status: res.headers.get("Status"),
        statusText: res.headers.get("StatusText"),
        headers: res.headers
    })
);

// receives the response body or false if not ok
// called on any response including 4XX or 5XX
function responseHandler(body) { ... }

// called when the server does not respond
// or if the responseHandler throws
function serverError(errorEvent) { ... }

// never generates console.error
fetch2("nonexistent.html")
.then(r => r.ok && r.text())
.then(responseHandler)
.catch(serverError)
```

### window.onerror

To clarify your question, there **is** [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event). It is not fired when the response code is 4XX or 5XX, since it is still a valid response, not error. Error is fired only if the server doesn't respond.

### console.clear

console.clear() is not the right approach, since it clears all the console notes, not just network errors. In my use case, I wanted to ping the server every minute to check if it is currently available. It was daunting to debug it: to browse through thousands of console errors from the ping and look for real errors.

Comment: Brillian!!! One caveat: if you want the 4XX body, the XXX should be async and await on `orig.text()` a la: `const proxyResponse = async orig => orig.status<400 ? orig : new Response(await orig.text(),...})` . (If the error text isn't worth waiting for, just provide some static text or an empty body: `const proxyResponse = orig => orig.status<400 ? orig : new Response("hi mom!", ... })` .)

Comment: The 202 status value is key. With other statuses `new Response()` throws an error unless you specify all the correct properties correctly.  202 lets you slide by with just a status value, as in `new Response(null, {status:202})`. This should be the accepted answer, as it is the only one that suppresses the console messages for all users, not just the developer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this in 2023, there's a checkbox for "hide network" under settings in the console tab.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) to perform XMLHttpRequest requests, the errors will be logged into the worker script context so they will not appear on the console unless this context will be specifically chosen for display.