# Check if file exists but prevent 404 error in console from showing up

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check to see if a file/page exists via JavaScript but prevent the 404 Error from showing up in the console?

Comment: Why do you care if the 404 error appears in the console? Developers (and other tech savvy types) are the only ones who will ever open the console.

Comment: Because when scanning the console for errors while debugging, it would be great if these specific 404 errors (that are expected) were muted.

Comment: At least in Chrome, there does not seem to be a way to suppress these errors in the console.

Comment: You will have to make a server side script that takes a filename as a parameter and checks if it exists. Then load that script with AJAX

Comment: you want to check the file on client side or server side??

Comment: There are specific cases where it would be gr8 to check on client side if file exists on server. For example when writing unit testing framework, it would be good to check if specified file (module) with tests exists on server before loading, without throwing error. And polluting console is ugly, and in this case undesired.

Comment: Polluting the console is more than ugly; it also takes up memory and makes things slower and slower the more output accumulates in there.

Comment: There is a solution (if you can control the backend). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165242/3119283

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Seems like the answer is: No. Can't avoid getting a 404 error in the console unless you kick off a call to a server-side script to check file existence.

Comment: You can catch error, but it is still logged into console, so looks like throw is somewhere in native implementations, and only catch of re-thrown error is possible. Or maybe error is thrown after logging. Anyway, couldn't find solution to that neither.

Comment: making the request inside a try{} catch{} helps mask the error in IE, but not other browsers.

Comment: This feels like such a bad implementation. :(

Comment: @aleclarson It really does. It should be valid to try to request a resource, have it come back as not available, and catch that as an exception.

Comment: Years after the question, the answer is finally [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75848002/343721).