# Treating Ajax error prevents showing the error on console

Tags: jquery, ajax, console.log

I have an Ajax call, and the server sends me an HTTP 412 error when the user forgets to fill some field.

I can treat the error calling a function to show to the user the error, but I don't want the error to appear on the browser console. How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent unhandled jquery ajax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481598/prevent-unhandled-jquery-ajax-error)

Comment: Why don't you just **validate the form** before sending it to your php file?

Comment: I will do this. I want to have the client validation and the server validation too. I'm creating a REST Service that should validate the data send to the server.