# Surpress 404 image not found error on <img> html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is it possible to surpress img not found log message from html image tag in Angular 5.

I try to do:

```
  <img [src]="default_url+'_'+id+'.png'" [alt]="default_url+'dummy.svg'"  onerror="this.src=this.alt;return null;">
```

So showing the user image by id and if there is no image i would like to replace it with the dummy.svg.

This is working but delivers error (404 if dummy replace the main image) on console log. 
Which I would like to surpress.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can suppress console errors for image load ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can prevent the error to be shown in the console if the image url is not right, but you might try with a try-catch.

The responses on this thread my help you:  [Eliminate 404 url error in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915582/eliminate-404-url-error-in-console)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.