# How to catch jquery exception on ajax bad request?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am saving user model like this:

```
this.model.save(data,{
                    success: function(user) {
                        console.log(user);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    }

                });
```

REST api returns 400 (Bad request) when for example user name is not unique).
In console the "error" is displayed but BEFORE it there is jquery execption:

```
POST http://localhost/cms/users.json 400 (Bad Request)
```

how can I catch this exception so its not thrown to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptions are showed up on console as a feature of the browser (plug-in in case of Firebug). You cannot turn it off and it doesn't affect your code flow in any manner. You should be ignoring it.

[Check this for another similar q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035466/check-if-file-exists-but-prevent-404-error-in-console-from-showing-up)