# Angular suppress 404 in console when using fallback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, ionic-framework

So I am using a custom directive that loads a secondary image source if the first image source resolves to a 404 using this directive.

```
  .directive('errSrc', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('error', function() {
          if (attrs.src != attrs.errSrc) {
            attrs.$set('src', attrs.errSrc);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

This works great, and if a ng-src="" resolves to 404 then it loads the err-src="" that is on that image and replaces it. However is there a way to suppress the 404 message generated in console? The function works fine but it is really hard to debug when you see 404 image missing 100 times in a row.

Comment: I think there is not way to do this, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7041565/2435473)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pankaj Pakar pretty much answered it, after much googling it seems that this is not possible currently. Closing.