# How to handle HTTP code 4xx responses in fetch api

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I was wondering how we should handle 400 from backend when we use ajax function. We can make if statement in promise resolve function and check if res status is 400. Different approach is making wrapper service for fetch, and when we got 400 from server we throw exception. How to deal with that problem ?

Comment: 400? A proper fix for this might be to re-architect an entirely new way to get the data. Maybe make 1 request with parameters and having the API patchwork all the data together.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I believe the OP means a `4xx` HTTP error code.

Comment: @TomG That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes, I mean 400 error code, for example invalid password when someone login

Comment: Actually, @ArturKasperek, I think that an invalid password would properly throw a 409 Conflict status: the server was able to process that request but found that there were issues related to the resource (i.e., the user).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd suggest a wrapper that checks `response.ok` which will be true if the response code is 2xx.

Note this statement from the [MDN page on `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch):

> An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that
> the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has
> a value of true. An HTTP status of 404 does not constitute a network
> error.

Here is a wrapper like this:

```
function fetchData() {
    return fetch.apply(null, arguments).then(response => {
         if (!response.ok) {
             // create error object and reject if not a 2xx response code
             let err = new Error("HTTP status code: " + response.status)
             err.response = response
             err.status = response.status
             throw err
         }
         return response
    })
}
```

Comment: So we're forced to use `then` even if the rest of the code uses `async`/`await`?

Comment: @sleighty - No, you can use `await` just fine with `fetch()` if you want.

Comment: I actually realized that [there's just no way to get rid of the 404](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041565/3403247) being printed to the console, even if you `.catch()` or `try`/`catch` it.

Answer (score 9):

This way we can handle all types of status accordingly.

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify({ user_email: email }),
}).then((response) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => response.json()
    .then((json) => resolve({
      status: response.status,
      ok: response.ok,
      json,
    })));
}).then(({ status, json, ok }) => {
  const message = json.message;
  let color = 'black';
  switch (status) {
    case 400:
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case 201:
    case 200:
      color = 'grey';
      break;
    case 500:
    default:
      handleUnexpected({ status, json, ok });
  }
})
```

[inspiration](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203#issuecomment-266034180)

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating it into your HTTP abstraction is probably a good idea. Perhaps with some sort of `options` argument:

```
const myFetch = (method, path, {headers, strictErrors, whatever}) => {
  // fetch here, if strictErrors is true, reject on error.
  // return a Promise.
}

myFetch('GET', 'somepath', {strictErrors: true})
  .then(response => {})
  .catch(err => { /* maybe 400 */ });
```

A wrapper around `fetch` is generally a good idea, `fetch` is a relatively low level function. Just as it isn't a good idea to directly create new XHR objects everywhere, I believe it isn't a good idea to directly call `fetch()` in various parts of your application. It's akin to a global variable, in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I've found for this is to wrap it in a new Promise, and if `response.ok` is false, reject the Promise with the error context.

```
/**
 * Parses the JSON returned by a network request
 *
 * @param  {object} response A response from a network request
 *
 * @return {object}          The parsed JSON, status from the response
 */
function parseJSON(response) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => response.json()
    .then((json) => resolve({
      status: response.status,
      ok: response.ok,
      json,
    })));
}

/**
 * Requests a URL, returning a promise
 *
 * @param  {string} url       The URL we want to request
 * @param  {object} [options] The options we want to pass to "fetch"
 *
 * @return {Promise}           The request promise
 */
export default function request(url, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(endpoint  + url, options)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return resolve(response.json);
        }
        // extract the error from the server's json
        return reject(response.json.meta.error);
      })
      .catch((error) => reject({
        networkError: error.message,
      }));
  });
}
```

(Top comment on https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203)