# .catch() in react-native's fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch

This is my code to handle signUp

```
handleSignUp(){
    console.log('Clicked')
    fetch('http://laptopIp:9999/signUp',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            Accept:'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
            body:JSON.stringify(this.state),
    })
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log("here")
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({error:false})
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e)
        console.log("in error")             
    })
```

this is express server handling the requset

```
router.post('/signUp',function(reqs,resp){


MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,database){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{

        var dataBases = database.db("thaparApp")

        dataBases.collection('userLogin').find({'email':reqs.body.email}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }else if(result[0]){
                resp.status(403).send({"error":"email is taken"})
            }else{
                if(validateEmail(reqs.body.email)){
                    dataBases.collection('userLogin').insertOne(reqs.body)
                    resp.send()
                }else{
                    resp.status(403).send({"error":"Email is not correct"})
                }
            }
        })

    }
})
```

})
    }

What i am doing is sending same username from react-native and express is sending me error **403** but **React native is not handling that error in .catch() instead keeping that in .then()**

[image] 
as we can see in image That status code is 403 which is error and `.catch()` have console.log("in error") which is not getting print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle HTTP code 4xx responses in fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248231/how-to-handle-http-code-4xx-responses-in-fetch-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call is coming back from the server, although it's status is not what you expected, it's not an error to catch.

Try using fetch's `ok` to check whether the response was valid, for example:

```
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        //throw error
    } else {
       //valid response
    }
})
```

You can also access the response's status like:

```
response.status;
```

or also, statusText such as:

```
response.statusText;
```

checkout the below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/