Javascript fetch api is not resolving in success or error
I am building a react native app, where I am using a fetch api to get the login response. The code snippet looks as below :
 export function login(username, password) {

    const url = `${baseUrl}/login`;
    const usernamePassword = `${username}:${password}`;
    const encodedString = Buffer.from(usernamePassword).toString('base64');
    console.log('encoded : ', encodedString);

    return fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`,
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    }).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}

I tried a lot of things, but the last logger which gets printed is :
    console.log('encoded : ', encodedString);

No matter what I try its never printing the loggers added in then or catch.
a few observations :

if I remove the Authorization header, its start working fine (getting exception)
I am using a sprint-boot backend service and CORS is disabled in that
I tried hitting the same request with postman and I could get a 401 response code

Can someone please help resolving this.

This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40251448/21085480

Try to add user agent:
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`,
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
})


I tried it but it did not work

@amitgupta - since "user-agent" is a header, it should be placed inside the headers ... though I can't see why that would help

Yes, in my humble opinion, even I could not relate that why it could help
