# Angular2: 404 exception handling

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code to handle a 404 exception.

```
 fileExists(url){
        this.http.get(url)
                  .map(res => res.json())
                  .subscribe(
                      data => console.log(data),
                      err => console.log(err.status));  //when it fails
  }
```

When the code fialed it reaches to the line `err => console.log(err.status)`
But it shows the error on the console.

[image]

So, **how can i handle it, in a way that no error shows in the console?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if file exists but prevent 404 error in console from showing up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035466/check-if-file-exists-but-prevent-404-error-in-console-from-showing-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error line is produced by the browser. There is nothing you can do about it.

As workaround you could create an API on the server that doesn't respond with `404` (or any other error code) when requested file doesn't exist, and then handle the alternative error response in Angular code.