# XMLHttpRequest Send() throws error despite onreadystatechange handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I am using XmlhttpRequest to send a POST requests on localhost and chrome developer tools console and network to verify the requests.

I have two methods:
Method1 send the post requests.
Requesthandler handles the requests response.

When the request is successful (200) it does not throw an error and the request handler outputs a message on console. But when the request is unsuccessful. My console throws an error despite the request handler.

For example, If I purposely set the wrong url adress. I expect a 404 status Not Found exception and the request handler to output a message on console. Despite it happening, it still goes ahead and throws on the error on Send() Method.

**Why xmlhttprequest.send() throws errors despite handling responses on the onreadystatechange event?**

[image]

### Method1(Sends Requests)

[image]

### RequestHandler(Handles responses)

[image]

### Console Message:

[image]

### Thrown Error:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you make sure that `http://localhost:5101/lolo` with POST method works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if file exists but prevent 404 error in console from showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035466/check-if-file-exists-but-prevent-404-error-in-console-from-showing-up)

Comment: There's a fundamental error in the code: `xj.onreadystatechange = requestHandler()`, you should not call the function meant to be an event handler (and when that function doesn't return a function), instead refer the function.

Comment: @Ivar I did not know that you can not avoid getting a 404 error in the console on chrome despite attempting to error handle it. Thanks for the info