# jQuery: catch ajax exceptions

Tags: jquery, ajax

Many failed jQuery ajax requests are polluting my console with errors. Looking at the code which produces these console errors (jQuery 1.7.2, line 8240)

```
                // Do send the request
                // This may raise an exception which is actually
                // handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
                xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

I notice the comment explains why there is no `try`/`catch` there. However, even though I have an explicit `error` callback function in my `jQuery.ajax` request, I'm *still* not having those errors handled by `jQuery.ajax`.

How can I handle jQuery ajax errors in such a way that error messages do *not* appear in the console?

*Edit:* Below is my code snippet that does the ajax request, and the precise error message (in Chrome):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'xml',
    url: "./python/perfdata.xml?sid=" + (new Date()),
    success: function (data) {
        var protocols = $("Protocols", data).children();

        parseData(protocols);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        setTimeout(getData, 200);
    }
});
```

And here is the Chrome error message:

```
GET
http://zeus/dashboard/python/perfdata.xml?sid=Thu%20May%2024%202012%2016:09:38%20GMT+0100%20(GMT%20Daylight%20Time)
jquery.js:8240
```

Comment: Can you post both the code creating the AJAX request and the full error message.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Did you try adding a `try/catch` block around the `$.ajax` call? I'm not sure what that error means, but looks like it happens when trying to issue the request, and I think `.ajaxError` only works with errors on the response.

Comment: Could it be that these errors are XML parse errors?

Comment: I think these console messages are not exceptions at all, these are just notices from the failed network requests. You get similar when you have `<img>` tags referencing missing images. I doubt you will be able to suppress them.

Comment: I got these when the response from the server was empty.  Trying to figure out why that is.. will post update.

Comment: The problem was that I was opening the index.html from www.example.com, and the $.ajax request was being made to example.com. I used firebug console to make requests, starting from basic $.post and working up in small steps.

Comment: Hide the console errors as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847631/529273)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (in chrome works well) if for testing, by overriding the function "send":

```
$(function() {

    var xhr = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')){
        // I do not know if this works
        xhr = window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    var send = xhr.prototype.send;
    xhr.prototype.send = function(data) {
        try{
            //TODO: comment the next line
            console.log('pre send', data);
            send.call(this, data);
            //TODO: comment the next line
            console.log('pos send');
        }
        catch(e) {
            //TODO: comment the next line
            console.log('err send', e);
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'xml',
        url: "./python/perfdata.xml?sid=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
        success: function (data) {
            var protocols = $("Protocols", data).children();

            parseData(protocols);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            setTimeout(getData, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

​
[test](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/ULwF3/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a custom function to do so

```
 $(document).ajaxError(ajaxErrorHandler);
```

and set whatever you need to do in that handler

```
var ajaxErrorHandler = function () {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried that, but then `ajaxErrorHandler` is executed *on top of* the console error!

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me out :)

Answer (score 3):

did you try?

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    timeout:10000,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      //
    },
    complete:function(xhr,status) {
      //
    },      
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      switch (status){
      case 'timeout': {}
      case 'parseerror': {}
      case 'abort': {}
      case 'error': {}
      default: {}
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting 500 internal server error and when it was point me to the line `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );`

But when I checked apache logs ( for internal server error ) error was something else in some other code.

Please check that once too.