# How can I catch jQuery AJAX errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

When an AJAX request is submitted to a site, server-side errors are easily handled with the jQuery promise approach. `.done()`, `.fail()`, etc. However for some requests (e.g. to an invalid site or one that doesn't accept cross-origin requests), an exception occurs immediately as the call is made. Here's an example of one error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://someotherserver/api/blahblah`. Origin
>   `http://localhost:52625` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Yes, I know about CORS...that's not the issue. What I'm actually doing is trying a web api call to test if the server IP/name is correct

I'm aware of the `error` option in the jQuery request syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: remoteURL,
    type: 'GET',
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
}).etc.etc.
```

The error is handled here, but exceptions are still logged in the console. It seemed reasonable to wrap the above in a `try-catch` block, but that doesn't seem to help.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740225/jquery-catch-ajax-exeptions), but the solution involves hacking the jQuery code. Surely there's a better way to catch these errors and not clog up the console logs??

Comment: I don't think it is possible because that error logging is done by the browser network monitoring layer

Comment: Small temporary servers will be deployed in a field camp environment. My users will need the option to set the server IP address for the ajax web api calls. I need a way to test if the address is valid. If there's a better way I'm happy to hear about it. :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages , may be You will get Your solution.

Comment: @ripa: I'm afraid not - the error is generated before any server-side code is run.

Comment: @AR. before ajax post error is coming!!!! :(

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: remoteURL,
    type: 'GET',
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
}).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus != "success") {
        alert("Error: " + jqXHR.statusText);
    }
});
```

XHR Listener:

```
$.ajax({
    url: remoteURL,
    type: 'GET',
    xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function(evt){
            alert("an error occured");
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", function(){
            alert("cancelled");
        }, false);

        return xhr;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: I've  tried .always() but it is called after the ajax request is made, sometime afterwards. The browser errors I'm referring to occur immediately -as- the request is started.

Comment: hmm...you could try and add an XHR Listener before the request is send (wait a moment, editing answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use web developer console in google chrome. Press F12. And use Networks tab for checking response, And for JavaSvript and jQuery and Ajax errors you can use Console tab. :)

Try this by adding to your ajax function :

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 alert(errorThrown);
```

Comment: that would be for debugging purpose

Comment: @ShreejiShah: Yes, it's the console where I see the errors, of course. Your answer doesn't help with the actual problem. :p