# Opposite of success: function(data) - ajax

Tags: ajax

what is the opposite of -> success: function(data)

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   url: "/p.php",
   data: info,

   success: function(data){
```

I want to check if it is not success instead of if it is success...

Comment: try `error: function(){}`

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla can't I use both, success: function(data){} error: function(data){} ?

Comment: ofcourse, you can use both of them, there are `beforeSend`, `complete` etc also. You can use them in a single ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You catch success situation with success function and there is also error function. Please see the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864734/how-can-i-catch-jquery-ajax-errors) for detailed xhr catch mechanizm

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/p.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(data){
        //do something
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
```

Comment: some explanation about your answer would be great

Comment: if /p.php is not found, it is not showing any error, why?

Comment: have you tried `statusCode` ?  as `statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    },500: function() {
      alert( "internal error" );
    }
  }`