# Why does this jQuery AJAX post request throw an error despite the fact that the post is successful?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have made a [blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/49) in Laravel 8.

I am currently working on submitting comments and comment replies via jQuery (v3.5.0) AJAX.

The method for adding a comment:

```
public function add_comment( Request $request ) {
  $rules = [
    'msg' => 'required'
  ];

  $messages = [
    'msg.required' => 'Please enter a message'
  ];

  $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );

  if ( $validator->fails() ) {
    return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors( $validator->errors() )
                    ->withInput()
                    ->with( 'error', 'Please correct the errors below' );
  }

  $fields = $validator->validated();

  $comment = [
    'user_id'    => Auth::user()->id,
    'article_id' => $request->get( 'article_id' ),
    'parent_id' => $request->get( 'parent_id' ),
    'body'       => $fields['msg'],
    'approved'   => 0
  ];

  // Insert comment in the 'comments' table
  $query = Comment::create( $comment );

  if ($query) {
    return redirect()->back()->with([
      'success' => 'Your comment is pending.',
      'success_comment_id' => $request->get('parent_id'),
    ]);
  }

  if (!$query) {
    return redirect()->back()->with( 'error', 'Adding comment failed' );
  }
}
```

The comment form template:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">
        Your comment is pending
    </div>

    <div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--error">
        Failed to add comment!
    </div>

    <form class="commentForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.submit') }}" autocomplete="off">
        @csrf
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ isset($article->id) ? $article->id : $article_id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}">

            <div class="message form-field">
                <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>

                @error('msg')
                <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <br>
            <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

In the scripting file I have:

```
$(".commentForm").each(function () {
  var form = $(this);
  form.validate({
      errorElement: "p",
      errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

      submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
              url = form.attr("action"),
              data = form.serialize();
          $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              type: "post",
              url: url,
              data: data,
              cache: false,
              success: function () {
                form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                      .slideDown(250)
                      .delay(2500)
                      .slideUp(250);
                $fields.val("");
              },
              error: function () {    
                form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                      .slideDown(250)
                      .delay(2500)
                      .slideUp(250);
              },
          });
      },
  });
});
```

Even though the comments are successfully submitted, the alert made visible is `<div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--error">Failed to add comment!</div>`, because the script executes `error`, not `success`.

The Network tab shows two statuses, in this order: `302` and `200`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An AJAX event error itself gives you information about what's wrong. Have a look in the [JQuery manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function).

Comment: `302` followed by `200` sounds like the method handling `route('comment.submit')` is doing a `redirect()`?  A redirect is for a browser response, but for an AJAX request like this you just want to return a 200/JSON response?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want the `<div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">Your comment is pending</div>` element to be visible when adding a comment.

Comment: Yes, that is clear.  I asked about the response from the back-end method that handles the POST.

Comment: A `302` response is interpreted as an error by `$.ajax`, it comes from your backend controller method handling the POST request.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? Both parts could be debugged pretty simple, either in your browser's developer console or through XDebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is speculation as you haven't provided the requested details of the back end, but my guess is your controller method is actually intended for a non-AJAX request, ie a normal form POST which bounces you back to an index/list, eg:

```
public function store (Request $request) {
    // ...
    // Save new comment

    // Something like this, eg bounce back to the post/page where comments
    // are shown
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This results in first a `302` response status as the browser is redirected, and then a `200` for the target page response.  This is the standard [PRG pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827242/understanding-the-post-redirect-get-pattern) for a normal web app.  This is what you report as seeing in the network tab of devtools (and if you click the `200` response in the list and then the *Preview* or *Response* tabs you will see the full rendered HTML of your page).

But it is not how a method handling an AJAX request should respond.  The redirect is intended for a browser making a request - that won't work for a Javascript request.

And checking [the jQuery `$.ajax()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the `statusCode` section says (emphasis mine):

> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; **if it results in an error (including 3xx redirect)**, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

It is tangential, but this tells us a `302` is treated by `$.ajax()` as an error - which again matches what you are seeing.

For AJAX requests you usually want to respond with some kind of JSON that the calling Javascript can read and handle - eg show a success/error message.  That is typically done something like:

```
public function store (Request $request) {
    // ...
    // Save new comment

    // Return some JSON for the Javascript to handle
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => 'OK',
        'message'   => 'Comment added!'
    ]);        
}
```

And the JS calling that method might look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        // Do something with the returned JSON
        if (response.status === 'OK') {
            do_something(response.message);
        } else {
            // ...
    }
    // ...
```

If you want that one method to handle both normal browser requests *and* Javascript requests, [you can use `expectsJson()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#content-negotiation) to check what kind of response the client is expecting:

```
public function store (Request $request) {
    // ...
    // Save new comment

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        // Return some JSON for the Javascript to handle
        return response()->json([
            'status'    => 'OK',
            'message'   => 'Comment added!'
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to speculate. You can see all the code in **[this](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/49)** branch.

Comment: All relevant parts of the question should be here, on SO, not off-site.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The comment adding function: `public function add_comment( Request $request ) {`

Comment: Sorry, not sure what that means.  I don't see that in the question, and it obviously does not show the relevant part we're discussing (the response) ...?

Comment: OK ... so it is as I'd guessed.  In all possible cases - validation error, record OK and record failure, the method returns with `redirect()->back()`, which is inappropriate for AJAX.  Have you tried the fix I described? Why are we still here chatting about this? :-)

Comment: The form has to work with Ajax _or_ without, depending on the option chosen bt the admin.

Comment: My answer already describes how to do that ... ?

Comment: Great! What shall I do with `error: function () {..}` then?

Comment: As my answer describes, the problem here was on the back end, not the front end. For this problem at least, you don't have to do anything with your front end code. Your `error` callback should probably include some info about the failure, but that's unrelated to this problem. There are plenty of examples here on how to do that, [here's a random one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18864734/6089612).

Comment: Please give me a hand with **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77595127/4512005)** too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you use a > 3 jQuery:

Deprecation Notice: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

Comment: The jQuery version used is 3.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

seems like the issue lies in the way you're handling the response in the success and error callbacks of the AJAX request. In your success callback, you're not checking the response or its status to determine whether the submission was successful. Instead, you're just sliding down the success alert

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
        $fields.val("");
    } else {
        form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
    }
},
error: function () {
    form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
},
```

Don't forget to return a response from your controller method so u can check and confirm here on your blade file.

Comment: I tried that, does not work.