# Firebug console error HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: firefox, proxy, firebug, ntlm

I am behind a proxy at work (using NTLM authentication). Whenever I load up a page, my Firebug console gets flooded with messages like this:

```
"NetworkError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required - http://somewebsite/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
```

It does that for all URLs referenced on that page: JS, CSS, Image, whatnot.

The annoying thing is that the file is actually successfully loaded. It seems that Firefox hits the 407 Error, spams the log and then loads it anyway with the NTLM credentials.

Is there any way I can stop these useless errors from showing up, so they don't drown out the console messages I'm actually interested in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your using Firefox you can following the [tutorial](http://www.adamkoch.com/2012/05/04/moz-proxy-issues/) here and change the 'network.websocket.enabled' flag to false to avoid this issue.

Comment: While in some rare cases this still happens, this seems to work for the most part.

Comment: This is not working for me at all (behind a corporate firewall)

Comment: Setting `dom.workers.websocket.enabled` to _false_ worked for me (Firefox 36.0a2).