# Suppress writing errors to browser console from dojo/request

Tags: http, dojo, firebug

Does anybody know how to suppress errors from being shown in browser console when executing dojo/request.

For example, I make a post request to backend which returns HTTP 400 telling me that an error has occurred because of validation check.

I will handle it appropriately in my code, show some validation warnings but still dojo/request logs the error into console:

[image: Example]

This example is on HTTP500, but it's the same in HTTP400.

This is a code snippet

```
var results = request.post("/webapp/target/save", {
                data:       dojo.toJson(this._dataObject),
                headers:    this.headers,
                handleAs:   "json"
            });
```

There has to be a way to hide this on production code :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. Reporting network errors is not a feature of Dojo, nor plain vanilla JavaScript. Even `event.preventDefault()`/`event.stopPropagation()` when handling crude `XMLHttpRequest` or `console.error = function(){}` have no effect.

You can suppress network errors logging in Firebug:
[image]

[Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) and F12 Developer Tools in IE9 do not log network errors into the console. Chrome Dev Tools does and I cannot find the way to disable it.

Users do not use your application with Dev Tools opened, so they won't see any errors at all and those who are willing to see them have dozens of methods to accomplish that *hacking*. Anyway, I would also prefer having an option here.

Comment: Shame, I'm not trying any "security through obscurity" things, but I'd like to have a clear console anyway. I could return everything with code 2xx and parse my own object for errors status, but that seems a bit pointless and stupid :)