# catch 401 with angular get request

Tags: angularjs, get, http-status-code-401

I am making a get request to a service to check whether a certain key present - if it is, it returns some data, and if not, it returns a 401. I do not have control over the service - but I do not want to display the 401 in the console - that seems unprofessional, since in most cases this key won't exist. Is there a way to catch the 401 so it never prints to the console?

Right now I have the following - I can test whether the status is 401, but I cannot catch it prevent it from printing out to the console. Is this possible? I don't want a global handler on 401s, I just want to catch one for this particular request.

```
$http.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          result.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if(status === 401)
          {
            // I can test for a 401 here, but that doesn't seem to help
          }
          result.reject(data);
        });
```

Comment: You can't. That bad request error is handled by your browser, an angular exception handler also won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent ajax errors to be printed in the console.

One way to avoid that would be to return a regular `200` from the server with a specific content that you would handle as the missing key error client side.

Or you could use `console.clear()` right after the response, but I don't know if it is supported by all browser and it may not be a lot more "professional".

Comment: I changed my server to return boolean about authentication. Don't know if it is violating http-protocol but works better for route that only checks if there is valid session id in request.

Answer (score 0):

What you have achieved on catching the 401 seems to be done on the way it should be done [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor). For the question of console log on the error I have to say no much can be done [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207143/angular-avoid-console-trace-on-http-error): at least Chrome console automaticly marks the 401 events to console, without your code being involved at all. Something can be hacked [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors/14427545#14427545), but only on your own machine and browser.

So, **answer in short is** that don't worry, I suppose only coders will use console, normal Internet users on daily surfing won't lurk much into console anyways.

**Sources:**

[1] [Capture HTTP 401 with Angular.js interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230417/capture-http-401-with-angular-js-interceptor)

[2] [Angular avoid Console trace on $http error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207143/angular-avoid-console-trace-on-http-error)

[3] [Can I prevent the Chrome Developer Tools console from logging image 404 errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors/14427545#14427545)