# Why when http.post fails zone.js throws 404 Not Found while there is a catch and return object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

Maybe I don't understand it, but if I have a service and I catch any error from it, how come `zone.js` is throwing 404 not found, while I catch the error and also returning json object so the client will know what to do. How can I avoid that error in the console? Can I?

For example:

```
return this.http.post(this.callUrl, requestBody)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let body = error.json();
    return Observable.throw(body);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you import it? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

Comment: Yes I did and also
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: added to the question. This is from the browser console. I thought I don't need to see that if I catch the error

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine. I get a response from my service, but I also get this 404 on console, don't know why

Comment: @Kinduser you seems to misunderstood his question. AFAIK, you cannot prevent the http erros logs, you can handle it like you did. but I think it'll always appear in the console. I don't know if angular2 offers that option.

Comment: It seems this is a browser's normal behavior.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24208278/3721394 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/14427545

Comment: @Kinduser Sorry if I said it in bad tone, I just saw you're asking in the wrong direction.

Comment: @A.Akram It's all good. Forget.

Comment: I just wonder, do you even use `Observable` here? Like `Observable.forkJoin(return this.http.post(){})`?

Comment: Note that the union type `Response | any` is exactly the same as `any`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `handleError` function, the function you are passing to `catch` does not handle the error, it actually transforms the error into a new error and propagates that (fails with it). The purpose of `Observable.prototype.catch` is to *handle* errors and the purpose of `Observable.throw` is to *create them*. This error is then returned to introduce a failure in the resulting stream.

Here is what your code would look like using a normal Http interface

```
async performPostRequest(requestBody) {
  try {
    await response = this.http.post(this.callUrl, requestBody);
    return this.extractData(response);
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  const unwrappedError = error && typeof error.json === 'function'
    ? error.json() 
    : error;
  throw unwrappedError;
}
```

I see in the comments a discussion of what capabilities Angular 2 supports for handling http errors. It supports all of the cases you likely require, including handling 404 errors, but their documentation is very bad.
All of their http examples, and most of their examples in general, have too much code.

When I say, too much code, I mean it in the sense that they are full of more code than you should write and a lot of code you should not be writing at all.

You pasted something very close to their default error handler from their tutorial in this question, without noticing the behavior.

You should never do this obviously!

But in all seriousness, why do they handle all of the errors in all of their examples? Errors should always be unhandled by default so that they propagate up the stack and cause failure where they must.

To make a rule of always catching and rethrowing is a terrible practice.

If you want a generic error handler, it definitely does not belong in every service that consumes the source of a potential error, that is madness, but if you follow the examples, that is what you will end up with. Hundreds of lines of repeated, unmaintainable boilerplate that the next person who works on the project will have to slog through to understand your business logic.

**Also, you should *not* pass unbound methods as callbacks as you do in your example but that is a separate conversation.**

Comment: Downvoter please comment, so that I may improve or fix factual errors in this answer.

Comment: Alternately, if you downvoted because I said the angular examples teach poor programming practices, then please provide a counter argument.