# AngularJS image not found suppress error

Tags: angularjs, image, fallback

I am displaying a bunch of images in some gallery. Whenever an image is not found, I replace it with a "fallback" image.
Now whenever an image is not found, it will write a console error that the image is not found before replacing it with the fallback.

Any way I can avoid the error? When displaying 100+ images, my entire console log gets filled with errors.

Here is my template:

```
<img ng-src="{{profileImageUrl}}" fallback-src="img/default-placeholder.png" />
```

And the directive:

```
myAppDirectives.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
    var fallbackSrc = {
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.bind('error', function() {
                angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);
            });
        }
    }
    return fallbackSrc;
});
```

The error I'm getting is a 404 not found for every image that's not available (the site took it down for example)

Comment: Nothing on you can in your code to hide this. If you are trying to load an image, and it gives you a 404, it is an error and Chrome will report it. However, looks like you can filter your console's output now, see this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors

Answer (score 2):

Using ng-src to resolve this issue

```
<img ng-src="{{image.url}}" />
```

Comment: Please make sure you configured correctly the fallback-src. I believe that if it's correct, there will be no error occurs. Also see http://jsfiddle.net/FdKKf/ .It worked well without logging in console.

Comment: In your fiddle, I got this in my console for the http://sdfsfsd image: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED