# How to prevent errors to be logged in browser console with onError html event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this:

```
<img src="/images/kjh5kh.jpg" onerror="myScript" />
```

myScript is replacing the images, which were not found.
It works great, but i don't want to see browser's console full of errors.
So, how could i catch the errors and prevent them from being logged in console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent the Chrome Developer Tools console from logging image 404 errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors)

Comment: Ajax a head first before setting the source?

Comment: [_**Here**_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie) a good explanation around this problem

Comment: Thanks for help, guys!
nAz, your url is most helpful, thanks again!