# Hide Chrome errors with JavaScript hook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a javascript code trying to reach for an image resource. sometimes the image exist and sometimes it doesnt (not on the domain, the domain doesnt exist and more).

```
<script>
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://notexistdomain1.com/myimage.png';
    img.onerror = function () {
        console.log('not found!');
    };
    img.onload = function (ev) {
        console.log(':)', ev.status);
    };
</script>
```

I would like to hide chrome errors from being displayed on console and network:
[image]
[image]

Using javascript. is that possible?

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible if you want to auto-disable the errors via javascript.
The possible interactions, directly with the browser, are limited for security reasons (see [Chrome Javascript API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_other)).

If you just want to disable the error-log in your browser, see: [Can I prevent the Chrome Developer Tools console from logging image 404 errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427545/1349403)