# Angular JS catching server error Jsonp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to catch server error for eg 500 in my angular app. Unfortunately this construction fails:

```
            return promise = this.httpService.jsonp("serverurl")
            .success((response: any): ng.IPromise<any> => { return response.data; })
            .error((response: any): ng.IPromise<any> => { return response.data; });
```

I want to catch server response -  in this case simply the message. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise.

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log(response); // add console log of response
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log(response); // add console log of error response
  });
```

Or a interceptor can be used to "monitor" all http's:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (response.status === 500) {
          //DO WHAT YOU WANT
      }   
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (response.status === 500) {
          //DO WHAT YOU WANT
      }                
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Comment: Thank you this caused the proper window to appear on error. Is there a way to protect server error from showing in the web browser console window?

Comment: In the example i've updated 'response.status === 500' on the responseError. In the first example you are console.logging the error. Or about what console error are you talking about? :)

Comment: I mean that I can properly show to user proper message on 500 Error now. But if somebody starts console there is: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - " and the url of server. This is not crucial but if it is possible to prevent from showing this message in the console I would like to do so.

Comment: It's a browser specific behaviour. But have a look at following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors/14427545#14427545