# Disabling console log react

Tags: reactjs, frontend, console.log

I need to be able to disable the errors that are displayed in console. I tried the babel library but it only removes the console.log statements that are inside the code, what I need is to delete or the 500, 404, 400 errors do not appear in the console. My code is in react

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of API connection issues? Or just network calls that result in 500, 404, etc?  You do know that the browser does that as well, correct?

Comment: Cross pasting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807184/how-to-hide-console-status-error-message-while-fetching-in-react-js). You need to do ```.catch(err => { const mute = err })```