# Axios Stop 404 error appearing in the console.log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am checking to see if a resource exists via Axios, it is normal to expect a 404 to be returned if it is not present.

But, when the 404 is returned, it is displayed in the console. I have tried to catch the error, but this does not prevent it from being displayed by chrome.

```
        axios.get('/api/user/checkin').then((response) => {
            Vue.set(UserStore,'checkin', response.data)
            this.loading = false;
        }).catch((error) =>{})
```

I am checking to see if the user is checked if they are I will return a record of when they checked in and some details on the site.

If they are not then I have nothing to return so I am returning a 404. I could return a blank record but that does feel very restful.

Comment: try to wrap your code with try/catch

Comment: it is natural for a browser to indicate an network request error.

Comment: I believe there is a filter in the Chrome console to filter out any `Network Requests`, you can just uncheck it and it will stop showing you this.

Answer (score 5):

This is a **chrome behavior**. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986081/6705096) and [also this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/599#issuecomment-267421331).
 You can do `console.clear()` in **catch** as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57649496/6705096).

```
axios.get('/api/user/checkin')
  .then((response) => {
    Vue.set(UserStore,'checkin', response.data)
    this.loading = false;
  })
  .catch(() => console.clear()) // this will clear any console errors caused by this request
```

or
 `.catch(console.clear)` for short.

**But be aware that you will lose any previous console logs**.

**Edit:**

You may want to clear the console when you receive a 404 response only.

```js
axios.get('/api/user/checkin')
  .then((response) => {
     Vue.set(UserStore,'checkin', response.data)
     this.loading = false;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if(error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
      console.clear();
    }
  })
```

Refer to [handling errors in Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `console.clear` which would clear your whole console making it difficult to show logs that you actually need. Try checking the `Hide Network` option in the Chrome console options. It will hide all the network errors for you, which are probably the only thing showing from the network in console.

e.g.

Unchecked:

[image]

Checked:
[image]