# how to catch 400 bad request error in HTTP response in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, http-status-code-400

I try to catch error `400 bad request` like this:

```
catch((error: any) => {
    if (error.status === 500) {
        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }
    else if (error.status === 400) {
        console.log( 'error' );
        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }
```

but it still appears like this in the console:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem or remove this message on console?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the message? Some people have imgur blocked by work.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the console from logging the error on the client side.

Comment: x POST http:/api-service/sample 400 ( bad request )

Comment: Inlined image, fixed a bit of grammar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the browser's standard behavior and cannot be influenced by you or Angular.

If you get those messages a lot and it clutters your console whilst developing, you can filter the console. This is how you would do it in Chrome:
[image: filter network errors in chrome]

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427545/4694994

Comment: do you thinks this make a clean.console by js can be a solution?? or you think this is not a problem or error of the sistem????

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your first question correctly. Can you clarify?

Comment: In general, it's perfectly fine to catch errors and handle them on your client. That said, your server should only respond with 400, if the request was invalid. Don't use it for valid requests, that have a non-normal response. For example for 'empty content', you should use the success code 204.

Comment: You did solve my question thanks a lot

Comment: this happens with 403 and 409 as well. not sure how to handle this