# Angular 2 handle error although handled in code, zone.js throws error or pollyfills.bundle.js would throw an error

Tags: angular, web, polyfills

I am trying to handle error while a service call is made from my application. While calling the service as following, I am able to handle the error during service call.

```
searchRequests(Model):Observable<any>{
    this.headers1.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers1});
    return this.http.post(this.Url,Model,options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((err:any, caught:Observable<any>) => {return Observable.throw(new Error(err))})
  }
```

In my component I am handling the error like this and just printing over console, which works absolutely fine while printing

```
this.service.searchRequests(StringArray).toPromise().then((searchResponse => {
        this.selectedData = searchResponse;
    }))
.catch(err => console.log('Error while search service call ' +err));
```

As per my understanding, this should work okay. but when I receive an error while service call, there is an error received from Polyfills.bundle.js over console. This is something I am not able to handle. Is there a way this error can be handled and there is no error over console. not sure how can I handle error in libraries. Any help would be hugely appreciated

Error at console is 
POST https:localhost:8080/searchRequests500 (Internal Server Error)  zone:js:2933

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the REST concepts this is the expected behavior of all REST APIs.

But if still want to remove the errors in the console, then I am afraid then that you can't really do anything, this is the behavior of Chrome browser.

Here is the link below for more info.

[Can I prevent the Chrome Developer Tools console from logging image 404 errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337351/can-i-prevent-the-chrome-developer-tools-console-from-logging-image-404-errors)