# jQuery ajax: how to prevent 404 errors spam in chrome DevTools?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I'm communicating with CouchDB via jQuery ajax, and '404' errors are expected by REST contract. But for each requests that ends with '404', '412' or so, google chrome write a red error line in DevTools console, like this:

[image: chrome DevTools]

Is it possible to somehow configure jQuery so '404' is not an error for given request? Fake errors spam clutter output and i can miss real errors or some `console.log` while looking at hundreds of fake '404' and '412' "errors" :).

Comment: Sorry, my friend, this is just another example of how REST is a poor fit for HTTP-hobbled ecosystems, such as browsers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not possible programmatically, due to the potential for a script to misuse the blocking or filtering of errors in the console to hide its activities from the Chrome user.

You can of course filter messages in the console by Error, Warn, Debug.

You can add your voice to [those asking for more powerful capabilities to filter console messages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-chrome-developer-tools/filter%2420console%2420messages/google-chrome-developer-tools/X1fzw52Ci9Y/P2IfjHBLoE0J) in Chrome, so when you view the console you can filter out the messages that clog it up. One of the posts does offer a tool to tag your own console messages and then filter them.

If you want to highlight an error in the console, you can add styles to it when logging in your own code. E.g the following will make the message stand out:

```
console.log("%cUser %s has %d points", "color:orange; background:blue; font-size: 16pt", userName, userPoints);
```

Comment: It [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75848002/343721) possible now.

Answer (score 4):

Bit of a necropost:

For the record, Chrome and Firefox have since added features that let you ignore network-specific errors.

**In Chrome**, click the filter icon to see the checkbox:

[image: Chrome "Hide network messages" checkbox]

**In Firefox**, filters are broken down by category at the top of the window:

[image: Firefox "Net" console menu]

Comment: True, but there's still no way to prevent the errors going to the console via javascript.