# How to remove the console errors in axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, console, axios

Here's my code:

```
async [types.GET_DATA]({commit, state}, data) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/login', {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
        });
        console.log(res)
    } catch(e) {
        if(e.response) {
            console.log(e.response)
        }
    }
}
```

So, I return 400 Bad Request whenever user sends empty fields. What axios does is throws the error along with the error response. What I need to do is remove that console error message and only get the error response.

How can I do it?

Comment: While you *could*, I would think it might be more elegant to check the fields beforehand, and only send out the request if they're non-empty? Just an idea

Comment: Well, that's cool but I prefer backend validation

Comment: so in this case use a promise based approch

Comment: async/await is there already :)

Comment: You should always validate in both frontend and backend

Answer (score 2):

It is actually [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379746/1913115) to do with JavaScript. This is due to security concerns and a potential for a script to hide its activity from the user.

The best you can do is [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847631/1913115) them from *only your* console.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error you can catch it like this:

```js
axios.get("https://google.com").then(response => {
  console.log("Done");
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("Error");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async [types.GET_DATA]({commit, state}, data) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/login', {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
        });
        console.log(res)
    } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, this will log on `err` the body of the request (e.g. if it gives a 401) which would expose to the logs the email and password.