# Fetch API, Chrome, and 404 Errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

I'm playing around with `fetch`, and I noticed that only Chrome displays an error when a resource I am fetching doesn't exist (aka a 404):
[image]

Both Edge and Firefox don't do that, and 404 errors using fetch don't seem to trigger a NetworkError to have my catch error handler to get notified. **What should I do to avoid this error in Chrome?**

In case you need this, my full code looks as follows:

```
fetch("https://www.kirupa.com/book/images/learning_react2.gif", {
    method: "head",
    mode: "no-cors"
})
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 200) {
        console.log("file exists!");
    } else {
        console.log("file doesn't exist!");
    }
    return response.text();
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error ", error);
});
```

Thanks,
Kirupa

Comment: There’s nothing at https://www.kirupa.com/book/images/learning_react2.gif so the server sends a 404 response to all clients regardless. But you prefer that browser devtools not show a 404 despite the fact that’s the actual status in the server response?

Comment: If this only happens in devtools then that is totally fine. That file not existing is deliberate. The 404 showing up as an error seemed a bit odd. As long as end users don't see the error, then I am not too concerned.

Answer (score 6):

> only Chrome displays an error when a resource I am fetching doesn't
>   exist (aka a 404)

I'm seeing this as an error in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

### Code I'm using

I tried to replicate what you're saying using the following run with [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).  There is no "data.json" file.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Async Test</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Async Test</h1>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

#### index.js

```
(async function() {
  let a;
  try {
    a = await fetch("./data.json", {
      method: "head"
    });
    console.log("No error");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Caught an error");
  }
  console.log(a);
}());

(function() {
  fetch("./data.json", {
      method: "head"
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log("No error");
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Caught an error");
    });
}());
```

### Dev Tools Screenshots

#### Chrome

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

#### Firefox

[image: Firefox Dev Tools]

#### Safari

[image: Safari Dev Tools]

### Analysis

The only way for the browser to know whether the resource exists is to actually make the network request.  Chrome always logs network request errors like **404**.  It's why you probably see a lot of errors about favicons when a site you visit doesn't have one.

You can't force your client to not see them with your own code, but a user can opt in to have the error not show up for them by changing their own browser settings.  See [this answer to Suppress Chrome 'Failed to load resource' messages in console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847631/691711).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to handle the error yourself and actually trigger a `Promise.reject()`. Something like this

```
fetch("https://httpstat.us/500", {
    method: "head",
    mode: "no-cors"
})
.then(status)
.then(res => res.json())
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
});

function status(response) {   
    if (response.ok) {
        return response;
    }
    return response.json().then(res => Promise.reject(res));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share this code snippet to show another way of using promise chain while fetching through an API.

```
<script>
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

fetchApi(url);

function handleData(data){
  console.log('succesfull:', data)
}

function fetchApi(url){
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject({err: response.status}))
    .then(data => handleData(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('Request Failed:', error));
}

</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of the console logging errors

Answer (score -2):

You can try pass function which is called when promise is rejected. You can do that by passing second function in `then`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise