# proper error handling in an asynchronous async/await function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm a little bit confused about the right way to handle errors in an `async` function in javascript.

```
async function getWeatherAW(woeid) {
        try {
            const result = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${woeid}/`);
            const data = await result.json();
            const tomorrow = data.consolidated_weather[1];
            return data;
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(`Error catch-Statement: ${error}`);
        }
    }

const wrongData = 3442;
getWeatherAW(wrongData)
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Error .catch()-Statement: ${error}`);
})
```

This code ended up giving this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMNo0.png). I'm curious about why even if the catch-statement is triggered a `404` error is printed out to the console..

Would it also be better to not return the result from the `async` function and instead proceed in the function? I mean the data in the then-block seems to be undefinded when an error occurs in first place.. and if I need to call the function more often, I don't always need to write the `then` and `catch`, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*the data in the then-block seems to be undefinded when an error occurs*" - that's because your `try`/`catch` was handling the exception, and then returning `undefined`. You could return something else as well. But having `undefined` doesn't seem very useful, it would require an `if (data !== undefined)` every time, rejecting the promise and handling the error properly seems better.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019776/fetch-api-chrome-and-404-errors) about the browser logging errors from fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console prints a 404 message for all failed requests, regardless of whether the error is handled.

It's a debugging aid to show you that a request failed, not an indication that the failure wasn't handled.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks. So there is nothing to worry about, the error is going to be catched? :D

Answer (score 0):

the error says `cannot read property '1' of undefined`

```
async function getWeatherAW(woeid) {
        try {
            const result = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${woeid}/`);
            const data = await result.json();
            const tomorrow = data.consolidated_weather[1]; <----- this is undefined
            return data;
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(`Error catch-Statement: ${error}`);
        }
    }

const wrongData = 3442;
getWeatherAW(wrongData)
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Error .catch()-Statement: ${error}`);
})
```

My guess is `tomorrow` is initializing before data has been initialized - or that `data` does not have key `consolidate_weather`

doing `fetch.then()` may get the result you want

```
let tomorrow;
return fetch(url).then((result) => {
     const data = JSON.parse(result);
     tomorrow = data.consolidated_weather[1];
     return data;
}, (error) => {
    console.log(`Error .catch()-Statement: ${error}`);
})
```