# handling console network errors using fetch API

Tags: javascript, promise

i have code something similar like this

```
  fetch("http://httpstat.us/401",   {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
       "Accept": "application/json",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "token": localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        }            
    }
  ).then(response =>{
    if(response.ok){
      return Promise.resolve(response.json())
    }
    else {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
    }
 }
)
```

so in my headers if i wont send  the `token`  or say `localstorage` is not having `access_token` or it is `empty` then from server `401 error` is thrown in the console,
can any body please give me a way so that i can handle the error and it is not thrown in the console

And i don't want a solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console) because it is a simple hack which programmer dose it for his satisfaction , how can we tell the client to do all this kind of stuff. so i want a programmatic solution to avoid this.

Comment: `fetch(url, options).then(/* handle success  */).catch(/* handle error */)`

Comment: @Ray, Error in terms of *fetch* is that the response was not received. Otherwise the response is received successfully with its status whether it was 200, 403, or 500 etc.

Comment: exactly @AliAnkarali and i am getting the 4xx error in the console, how to stop it, even though i am handling in my code for unsuccessful response