# JS Double Fetch condition

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm working in get a list from a local file. But the folder sometimes can change. So come here to ask you guys if it's correct, because I think there is  a better way to do it, idk. Please help me :)

```
  fetch("./myJson.json")
     .then(res => { 
        if(res.status != 404)
           res.json() 
        else
           fetch("../myJson.json")
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => console.log(data))
              .catch(err => console.error(err));
     })
     .then(data => console.log(data))
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to `return` the nested promises from the callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to `return` the nested promises from the callback and use the [promise chaining feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572):

```
fetch("./myJson.json").then(res => { 
    if (res.ok)
        return res.json() 
    else
       return fetch("../myJson.json").then(res => res.json());
}).then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Nice Bergi!! Thanks!!
Just a detail... If the first fetch fails, an error 404 shows up in console. Can I tell him that "if the first fetch fails, the second one will solve it. You don't have to show any error in console about this first fetch."

Comment: The 404 will always show up in the console, you cannot prevent that from JS. You will need to use [different console settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console). Or actually handle the logic on the server side with a redirect.