# console log an error when fetching a 404 response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

My chrome console reports an error each time I execute a `fetch(urlObject, optionsObject)` with a 404 response. Since I expect to get some 401 and 404 response from the API I am calling I would like to remove this error. Is there any way?

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you're using your fetch?

Comment: I think you're out of luck bro... You maybe can disable it on your machine, but you can't programatically disable it on your end-users' machines, that I know of... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console

Comment: @TJBlackman this is the answer I hoped not to receive... Thanks for the reference :)