# Try/catch. Try statement is given an error even when It's not failing

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to implement try/catch on javascript with Fetch API using PATCH Method. Most of the time when the fetch success I get a 400 (Bad Request) error and I don't know why, I wonder If I'm forgetting to add an if statement inside the try statement to check the response status before jumping into the catch statement. I also created a function called retry() to not allow the user to make more than 3 failing calls. 
And if I make it fail I am not able to see the numberOfRetries log updated.

```
const retry = async (callback, numberOfRetries) =>
  await callback(numberOfRetries)

export const updateValue = async (name, active, numberOfRetries = 0) => {
  try {
    await fetch(`${apiUrl}/device/${name}?active=${active}`, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        active
      })
    })
    console.log('ok')
  } catch (error) {
    if (numberOfRetries >= 2) {
      return
    }
    console.log(`retry number ${numberOfRetries}`)
    return await retry(updateValue, ++numberOfRetries)
  }
}
```

[image: Console screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> when the fetch is successfull I get a 400 (Bad Request) error and I don't know why, it's jumping into the catch statement.

No, the `catch` block doesn't run. The error you see in the devtools log is because a network request failed with an HTTP error code. You can [disable the log messages in the console options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4500741/1048572).

As for why you are getting a `400` code, you have to check your serverside code - it suggests you are doing the request wrong.

> I wonder If I'm forgetting to add an if statement inside the try statement to check the response status

Yes, you forgot that as well. You should check for the [`.ok` property of the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok):

```
export const updateValue = async (name, active, numberOfRetries = 0) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/device/${name}?active=${active}`, {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        active
      })
    })
    if (response.ok) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      console.log('ok')
      // console.log(await response.text()) or something
    } else {
      throw new Error("HTTP Error "+response.status);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (numberOfRetries >= 2) {
      return
//    ^^^^^^ should be `throw error` instead of returning undefined?
    }
    console.log(`retry number ${numberOfRetries}`)
    return updateValue(name, active, ++numberOfRetries)
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pretty surely you'll want to pass through the arguments
  }
}
```

Comment: check my edited response above and let me know what is your take

Comment: @Bergi take a look at my code above I have a retry() function which accepts a callback in order to control the retries.
I've tried your solution, but now when fails starts to throw lot of **PATCH device/1?active=undefined 400 (Bad Request)** errors in my console, like 3000 or more, you think should I use a setTimeOut to stop? also my CPU is getting overheat

Comment: @Kaiser91 The `retry` function that you posted does nothing but immediately call the "callback" with the single argument you gave it, I've inlined the whole thing for simplicity. But there's a mistake in your code, you will want to pass all three arguments.

Comment: @Kaiser91 I've updated my answer to clarify. And yes, an infinite loop is to be expected when you pass the `numberOfRetries` in the wrong position so that it always takes the default of `0` in the recursive call.

Comment: @Bergi yes you are right I was not passing the correct parameters to the function, now I get why this infinite loop, now It's working as expected