# Prevent logging errors to console when using Axios interceptor

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, axios, interceptor, http-status-code-401

I've implemented axios interceptor in my VueJs project, which looks like this:

```
      axios.interceptors.response.use(
    async (response) => {  
      return response;
    },
    async (error) => {

      const originalRequest = error.config;
      const isPublicUrl = [
        '/account/login',
        '/account/register' 
      ].some(url=> originalRequest.url.includes(url)); 
      if(isPublicUrl){
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      if(error.response.status!==401){ 
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      const token:TokenOpts =  store.getters['auth/getToken'];
      try{
        const res = await AuthService.refreshToken(token); 
        const newToken = res.data;
        store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken',newToken);
        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken.accessToken}`; 
        const originalResponce = await axios.request(originalRequest); 
        return Promise.resolve(originalResponce); 
      }
      catch(error){ 
        return Promise.reject(error);
      } 
    }
    )
```

I can refresh my token and then send original request, here no problems. 
   My problem is that when I intercept an error, and end up inside error handler:  ***async (error) => { HERE ...*** I already have an error in Chrome console. How can I prevent logging this error into the console?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with VueJs. All errors will be logged in the console as that is the default option enabled in your browser. Follow this link to disable your network error messages. [Suppress Chrome 'Failed to load resource' messages in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console)

Comment: Mark this as resolved if this is what you are looking for