# why am getting console error when request send 400 response?

Tags: reactjs

we are using react and node for our project. after the google signup flow if the user already exists it display the console error. even after we checked there is no console printed. I have to remove the console error
[image: console error display]

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google Chrome and any modern browser (tried with Firefox too) prints the network error logs in console in that way.

Check this Stack Overflow question for more information:

- [Suppress Chrome 'Failed to load resource' messages in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console)