# removing unfetched data from developer console . (error get data from api with javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, api

i want to do:
I am using this code in different areas and some token addresses show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()" error in the development console. if it can't get data from that token address, let it detect it and prevent it from showing an error

javascript

```
    checkPrice();

function checkPrice() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.dex.guru/v1/tokens/0x3993453b9587e06a0e925727fd844d2d2babd39f-bsc/",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#price").html("$" + data.priceUSD.toFixed(8));
            checkPrice();
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
        <div class="col text-end">
            <span id="price">-</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console

Comment: TL;DR - you can't suppress the request/response from appearing in the developer console - why is it important?