# Angularfire - getDownloadURL() error can't catch

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, error-handling, firebase-storage

Version: "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0"

Is there any way to stop the logs of 404 image not found incase file doesn't exists in firebase storage?

[image]

Although I've handled this error here

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the error code is `storage/object-not-found`? [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors) is a list of possible error codes. Also, have you logged `JSON.stringify(e)`? That could tell you what the actual error code is.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @JoeMoore Yes, the code is storage/object-not-found

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console/75848002#75848002) might be worth looking at.