# Fetch Javascript throws Error 404 in console even with a `try...catch` method

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

I cannot get rid of the error showing in console, even with nested `try...catch`
Here's the function :

```js
async function checkFileExists(url) {
    try {
    return await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        })
        .catch(() => { return false; });
    }
    catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There's also a `try...catch` at the call of the function

```js
        try {
            const imgLongExists = await checkFileExists(imgLongPath);
            if (imgLongExists) { cardImgLong.src = imgLongPath; }
            else { cardImgLong.src = "img/blank-long.png"; }
        }
        catch (error) {
            cardImgLong.src = "img/blank-long.png";
        }
```

Comment: *"I cannot get rid of the error showing in console..."* That's true, you can't (easily). It's a choice made by the Chrome development team. I think they're considering changing it. See [the previous question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console), one of which claims to have a way to avoid them (but it's very much non-trivial).

Comment: Side note: There's no need to combine `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch` in most situations, including this one, and doing so is usually confusing. Also, you can just use the `ok` property from the `Response` object: https://pastebin.com/bgpBXGVM

Comment: Okay, I thought there would have been a way to do this for 12 years, but thanks anyway!

Comment: SO isn't an old-style forum, questions and answers get updated here, rather than going stale as on old-style forums. The answer I'm referring to, for instance, was posted just earlier this year.