# how can i hide the api request unauthorized console log in blazor web assembly?

Tags: blazor, hosted-blazor-webassembly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO66M.jpg)Try to access the authorized server side api method and getting unauthorized error in response. i handled them  to refresh token but that unauthorized error with api url has been logged in browser console from somewhere. how to clear them.

I have implemented JWT token authentication with blazor webassembly. Try to access the authorized server side api method from client and getting unauthorized error in response. i handled them  to refresh token but that unauthorized error with api url has been logged in browser console from somewhere. how to hide that error from console log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress Chrome 'Failed to load resource' messages in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500741/suppress-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-messages-in-console)

Comment: This behaviour is part of the underlying XMLHttpRequest object, and is not specific to any particular framework - including Blazor. I would recommend searching stackoverflow or the web for different approaches to this.

Comment: It might be helpful to understand your motivation for wanting to hide 401s (and maybe other http logs) from the console. Do you just want a cleaner dev experience, or do you want to hide messages from the end user?

Comment: Thanks. I want to hide the message from end user, or I don't want to show my API URL to end user when I am getting this error. is there any problem of displaying API URL ?

Comment: It is easy to monitor API calls made from the browser. If someone has opened up dev tools then there is a good chance they would know how to view all XHR requests in the network tab. I'm still not sure *why* you want to hide your API URL. You can go to any web app in the world and see what API calls are being made - is there a specific reason you have?

Comment: If you still insist on hiding calls to your API you should look into technologies that don't make API calls from the browser (e.g. ASP.NET MVC, razor pages, Blazor server, etc). You would probably then need to come up with a different approach to authentication. At that point I would then ask myself whether or not it's worth the time investment.

Comment: I thought it would make the application vulnerable. I just want to make sure that things are ok. Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem. As long as your API is secure and you are following good JWT procedure (e.g. short-lived tokens) there is absolutely no problem in someone knowing what your API urls are. The browser represents your user - anything the browser knows the end user can know. This - necessarily - includes the API urls that it needs to make calls to.